# Accessibility Service unable to display toast or any UI element after clearing the app from open app list

Tags: android

The Toast message generated from an accessibility service no longer appears when the app is cleared from the recent history of apps.

Here is the bare minimum code:

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService{
    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service connected");
        final Handler h=new Handler();
        Runnable w = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Beat",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                h.postDelayed(this, 1000*10);
            }
        };
        h.post(w);
    }
}
```

The Toast will appear every 10 Seconds until the app I cleared. And, when the app has been cleared, the Toast no longer shows even though the Accessibility service remain turned on.

Anybody knows about this? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: no, it is not. I figured out the reason and adding it as an answer for anyone else facing same. I was thinking about the reason for this behavior for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 1):

This is much of a device specific issue. The built in battery optimisation that came with the device kills all the background services when an app is cleared from the recent app lists. So, the accesbility service was also not running even though it's status was shown as enabled.

**Solution:**
Add the app to the protected list of apps.